# Align: Flush leftside to left and center align on center operator

Tags: align

Currently, I have something like this:

```latex
\begin{align*}
    \varsigma, \iota, t \models_{\fim} \texttt{p} \  \texttt{s}_{\texttt{i}_0} \ldots \texttt{s}_{\texttt{i}_n} 
    & : \Leftrightarrow \ 
    \eta_{\fim}\varsigma, \iota, t, \texttt{p} \ \texttt{s}_{\texttt{i}_0} \ldots \texttt{s}_{\texttt{i}_n}  \\
    %
    \varsigma, \iota, t \models_{\fim} [\texttt{s} \triangleleft \sigi] 
    &: \Leftrightarrow \ 
    \varsigma(t)(\texttt{s}) \equiv \sigi  \\
    %
    \varsigma, \iota, t \models_{\fim} \neg \varphi 
    &: \Leftrightarrow \ 
    \varsigma, \iota, t \not \models_{\fim} \neg \varphi  \\
    %
    \varsigma, \iota, t \models_{\fim} \varphi \wedge \psi
    &: \Leftrightarrow \ 
    \varsigma, \iota, t \models_{\fim} \varphi \wedge \varsigma, \iota, t \models_{\fim} \psi 
\end{align*}
```

Which resutlts in:

[image]

But I want something like:

[image]

Happy to be redirected if duplicate, but if I'm not mistaken I haven't seen a post asking for both left flush and center alignment.

Note: `flalign` doesn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `alignat`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\fim}{\langle \cdot \rangle}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
  \varsigma, \iota, t & \models_{\fim} \texttt{p} \ \texttt{s}_{\texttt{i}_0} \ldots \texttt{s}_{\texttt{i}_n} 
  && : \Leftrightarrow \ 
  \eta_{\fim}\varsigma, \iota, t, \texttt{p} \ \texttt{s}_{\texttt{i}_0} \ldots \texttt{s}_{\texttt{i}_n}  \\
  %
  \varsigma, \iota, t & \models_{\fim} [\texttt{s} \triangleleft \texttt{s}_{\texttt{i}}] 
  &&: \Leftrightarrow \ 
  \varsigma(t)(\texttt{s}) \equiv \texttt{s}_{\texttt{i}}  \\
  %
  \varsigma, \iota, t & \models_{\fim} \neg \varphi 
  &&: \Leftrightarrow \ 
  \varsigma, \iota, t \not \models_{\fim} \neg \varphi  \\
  %
  \varsigma, \iota, t & \models_{\fim} \varphi \wedge \psi
  &&: \Leftrightarrow \ 
  \varsigma, \iota, t \models_{\fim} \varphi \wedge \varsigma, \iota, t \models_{\fim} \psi 
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```